# Trouble shooting freezing/stalling issues in QGIS

Tags: qgis, debugging

I've been using QGIS for more than a year now (currently using 2.8.2 on MacOS 10.10.3, but also in Windows XP via VirtualBox for troubleshooting) and the application has been freezing and stalling quite a lot on me as I've been trying to do some analysis over the past several weeks such that I'm nearly at a standstill.

The sort of work I'm doing is relatively mundane doing analysis using a set of a few hundred data points (in CSV) and a series of shapefiles (Scottish Urban-Rural data, Deprivation, etc.). I've struggled to isolate the source of the failure and have tried a variety of things (converted CSV to shapefiles, messed around with using different CRS so that all are matching, have tidied up my CSV data, reimported data and layers into a fresh QGIS file, etc.), but can't seem to discover what is causing my issues.

I expect that having a better grasp on good practices for troubleshooting QGIS might help me to isolate what is going on, and so I'm wondering if a savvy user can recommend some good practices for troubleshooting this kind of issue in QGIS (when analysis operations are freezing or stalling). Is there a way to view progress in a console window? Or maybe there are some logfiles I should be checking for specific errors?

Comment: Are these issues happening in both Mac and Windows environments?

Comment: Not consistently, but this is partially why I'm wondering what to target for troubleshooting data so I can compare the two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open a ticket (bug report) in QGIS Tracker web site with your problematic data.

To do this, read these [guidelines](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Bugreports)

With all your data, the developers should be able to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this luca76, which I've done before. But part of what I'm wondering about is what sort of preliminary data collection might be useful in troubleshooting whether an issue lies in my CSV files, use of CRS, or some other user-side issue I'm just not anticipating, whereas the guidelines for QGIS bug tracker just recommend a backtrace, which I think is more useful for debugging a crash as opposed to a freezing app...?

Comment: Usually the QGIS for Windows is compiled without debug libraries, so the backtrace data would be useless. But if the freeze occurs in both Windows and Mac version, then the problem should be the data used for the project. Could you share your data so can we test if the freeze occurs to us, too?

Comment: I'd be very happy for help on this, though I suspect the admins would prefer I start a new question for this as debugging my specific freezing problem isn't quite what I had been asking for in this query. I'll open a new question and post the link here.